# How use textinputlayout in eclipse adt

Tags: android

I tried to implement textinputlayout in Eclipse ADT (not in Android Studio), I also include library android-support-design.jar.

But I got an error in rendering screen of XML file :

Error is :

```
cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you have Android Support Library, revision 22.2.0 or
   higher.
2. `TextInputLayout` is part of Design Support Library.
3. You need to `import <android-sdk>/extras/android/support/design`.
4. You need to `import
   <android-sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat`.

After importing design library, you need to edit project.proerties file as following:

```
# Project target.
target=android-21
android.library.reference.1=../v7/appcompat
android.library=true
```

Comment: android.library=true so project not run